# Preventing ActionView::MissingTemplate in a Backend-only (API) application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, response

My backend API-only application is responding to clients with a `RestClient::InternalServerError: 500 Internal Server Error` because of the following code ( and there being no templates to render ).

```
def create
    @project = Project.create(params.require(:project).permit(:name))
    @project.update_attributes(key: Devise.friendly_token)

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json { render json: @project }
    end
end
```

**Current Solution:**

Based on the Rails guide to `Layouts and Rendering`, this can be prevented by using `render json: @project`

Source: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

**The Ask:**

But I want to give the client the option of format, so the `respond_to` block is the more ideal choice.

Is there a way to combine these to use the first block but not result in a `500` error?

Thanks kindly.

Comment: What do you expect to be returned for the HTML format ?

Comment: I've seen offering multiple formats in many example applications... Maybe there's no value in allowing an HTML response if its an API only app?

Comment: If all clients are expecting JSON, I would ignore the requested format : remove the `respond_to` block, keep only `render json: @project`. That way the code is simpler, and easier to use by clients.

Answer (score 0):

What should the user see if he asks for an html response?

- If all requests should be handled like js, just take out the whole `respond_to` structure.
- If html should do something, you must create a view to return or just render something (or `render nothing: true`).
- If you want to return a better error, just remove the html part, this way the user will receive a `406 Not Acceptable`.